# Sum numbers in a string Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to sum all the numbers in a string, in the string there won't be any letters only numbers. The cell contains `112121`.

I tried using `SUM` and `CASE` with the `QUERY` Function, but `CASE` is not supported.

Example: `1121` = 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), REPT("(.)", LEN(A1))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

```
=INDEX(QUERY(,"SELECT "&REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1),"\B","+")),2)
```

- Convert A1 `TO_TEXT`
- Change All non `B`oundary to `+` using `REGEXREPLACE`
- Query's `Select` can accept math strings and perform calculations
- `INDEX` to remove headers

Comment: Nice. Thanks for explaining yours

Comment: interesting one, but does not work with array `A1:A`

Comment: @player0 Shouldn't be hard to join them all using `+`